# .BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.employee.dao.EmployeeDao

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am learning Hibernate JPA. I have created a simple program to read and write into MYSQL db using Hibernate JPA, but, when I start the server I get the below exception:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.employee.dao.EmployeeDao com.employee.controller.EmployeeController.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [${database.driver}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
```

I have searched for related questions in this forum but, could not find a suitable solution.

Please help...

I am new here and do not know how to paste my configuration files. Please let me know the process

Comment: By the looks of the exception, the real problem is that it's unable to autowire a DataSource instance.  EmployeeDao is dependent on an entity manager bean, which is dependent on the data source bean, so that's why it the top level exception says EmployeeDao.

Comment: @Ashwini Please share the source code for beans, context.xml file.